# BOX2D Kinematic Platform with parallax layer

Tags: physics, cocos2d-iphone, ios, moving-platforms

I am using a kinematic body for my moving platform on x-axis, so I set the linear velocity to `b2vec2(5,0)`.

When the player jump on the platform, it works like it is suppose to. But the thing is that my platform is on the obstacle layer and I am moving it with the parallax layer.

So if I `setTransform` the kinematic platform to follow the obstacle layer than it's physics will not work and the player will slip-off the platform.

I'm developing for iOS and using cocos2d api. Anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. I calculate the layer offset difference then minus it from the velocity and apply it to the setLinearVelocity rather than the setTransform method. Cheers.